# Is there a way to set a message expiry policy on a specific queue in Amazon MQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

Apache ActiveMQ offers the following setting to discard expired messages from a queue:

```
<address-setting match="exampleQueue">
   <expiry-delay>10</expiry-delay>
</address-setting>
```

Amazon MQ doesn't support `address-setting` as a configuration parameter. How can we set the expiration delay in Amazon MQ for a specific queue?

We know about the `timeStampingBrokerPlugin`, but that doesn't seem to be applicable to specific queues, only across all queues.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon MQ supports the element `policyEntry` with attribute `expireMessagesPeriod`.

#### XML Schema definition

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
  ...
  <xs:element name="policyEntry">
    <xs:complexType>
      ...
      <xs:attribute name="expireMessagesPeriod" type="xs:long"/>
```

#### Example

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry queue=">" expireMessagesPeriod="30000">
          <!-- other policy settings -->
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>
  <!-- other broker settings -->
</broker>
```

#### Resources

- [Elements and Their Attributes Permitted in Amazon MQ Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/permitted-attributes.html)
- [ActiveMQ XML Configuration](https://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html)